# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: sql, mariadb, heidisql

I have an issue while executing UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE vehicles2 SET limit = @newlimit WHERE model = @vehiclenew
```

Error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit = 1 WHERE model = 'crf450r'' at line 1

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: please share table structure also

Comment: please try this solution and let me know whether it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` is a reserved MariaDB/MySQL keyword, and so if your `vehicles2` table really has a column with this name, you will have to escape it with backticks:

```
UPDATE vehicles2
SET `limit` = @newlimit
WHERE model = @vehiclenew;
```

The best fix here is to actually *not* call your columns/tables/etc. using a keyword.  Change `limit` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Limit is a reserved keyword used to restrict the number of records to be returned in a query. If you have a column called LIMIT in your table, or any other name that matches a keyword for that matter, you have to use qualifiers around your column name so the database engine knows it is actually a column name and not a keyword.
Wrap your column name around backtick and it should work.

```
UPDATE vehicles2 SET `limit` = @newlimit WHERE `model` = @vehiclenew
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and let me know ,if still there is any issue.

```
DECLARE @newlimit INT,
@vehiclenew VARCHAR(100)
SET @newlimit= put your values here ,
@vehiclenew='put Your values'
UPDATE vehicles2
SET `limit` = @newlimit
WHERE `model` = @vehiclenew
```